# How to host 2 subdomains as lookalike destinations under one master domain?

Tags: customization, subdomains, domain

Due to restrictions on several required plugins, we cannot use multisite (some are not multisite compatible) at this time.  So we have 2 sites with e-commerce that will look essentially the same (same theme) but be operated as separate locations: location1 and location2.  Each location has separate inventory, same items, but different quantities.

Similar to a JimmyJohns where you would select the location you are closest in order to place your order.  So perhaps I can set a cookie determining the chosen domain?

So the users going to www.shop.com would need to select location1 or location2 (ideally from a drop down or other header area button) that would move them to location1.shop.com.  They could review products, purchase items, and schedule delivery with that site.

If they switch over to location2 (location2.shop.com) via the header area popup, the cart would be reset because they are different locations with different inventories.  Same items, but different inventories in each store.

How can we configure individual sites www., location1., location2., so the user can easily switch between them, redirecting between the subdomains?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't really think this is a WP-specific question. If you're not using multi-site then the solution is presumably going to be a WP-independent solution, no?

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to "redirect" anything... Your question states you have two sites that are only similar in appearance. What's wrong with hosting them on their separate (sub)domains and just providing links back and forth as needed?

Comment: I think of it being wp-specific in that there might be a plugin to
* allow moving the user to different sites (settable in the admin)
* Keep the content (apart from the ecomm) synched
* Establish a menu on the www. site that links to content on the sub-sites.
* potentially shares users so we could have a single signon potential

Comment: I guess there is nothing wrong with providing the links between them, I was hoping there was a technical way to have the 2 sites be only the ecomm sites (which have to look the same but show different inventories), and all other content (about us, help, contact, etc) be under the main site.